# How to create a Wicket MarkupContainer to use in JUnit testing a utility class?

Tags: java, junit, wicket

I wrote a utility class that generates Wicket components from annotated models and adds them to the MarkupContainer that is passed in as method parameter.

For the unit tests of this generator a MarkupContainer is required. I tried it this way:

```
final MarkupContainer container =
    new MarkupContainer("container") {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    };
```

This compiles, but running the test throws this exception:

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException:
    There is no application attached to current thread main
```

So the MarkupContainer container requires additional objects in the environment not defined as constructor parameters. From the documentation I can't figure out what they are.

I looked at WicketTester but did not find a method to make it produce a MarkupContainer.

Can you suggest a way to generate a MarkupContainer implementation to use in JUnit tests, preferably without having to create a complete web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wicket components generally need an application bound to the current thread. Have a look at what (Base)WicketTester does internally. The easiest solution to be able to create a WebMarkupContainer is by instantiating a WicketTester - it takes care of the background initializations:

```
@Test
public void testWmc() throws Exception {
    WicketTester tester = new WicketTester();
    new WebMarkupContainer("id");
}
```

Comment: Together with adding a Maven dependency for the servlet API with test scope this works, thanks.